# I'm getting error cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT sum(sum(DATEDIFF(DAY,LeaveBreakup.StartDate,LeaveBreakup.EndDate)+1)) AS totalNoOfDays,
       LeaveApplication.Id,
       LeaveBreakup.StartDate,
       LeaveBreakup.EndDate,
       LeaveApplication.ReasonForLeave,
       LeaveApplication.ProcessorComment,
       Team.Name,
       LeaveTypeDetail.Name
FROM LeaveApplication
INNER JOIN Employee ON LeaveApplication.Employee=Employee.Id
INNER JOIN Team ON Employee.Team=Team.Id
INNER JOIN LeaveBreakup ON LeaveApplication.Id=LeaveBreakup.LeaveApplication
INNER JOIN LeaveTypeDetail ON LeaveBreakup.LeaveType=LeaveTypeDetail.LeaveType
WHERE Employee.Team=5
  AND LeaveStatus!=0
  AND LeaveBreakup.StartDate BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '01-31-2016'
  AND LeaveBreakup.WhichHalf=0
GROUP BY LeaveApplication.Id,
         LeaveBreakup.StartDate,
         LeaveBreakup.EndDate,
         LeaveApplication.ReasonForLeave,
         LeaveApplication.ProcessorComment,
         Team.Name,
         LeaveTypeDetail.Name
ORDER BY LeaveBreakup.StartDate
```

Comment: Why do you want the `sum` of the `sum`? That's the error.

Comment: You dont need those 2 SUM at the beginning SUM(blah)+1

Comment: I just want the total sum of that column 'totalNoOfDays'

Comment: thanks in advance :)

Comment: Look into WITH ROLLUP or use a subquery to sum totalNoOfDays

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT sum(totalNoOfDays) as total,
a.Id,
       a.StartDate,
       a.EndDate,
       a.ReasonForLeave,
       a.ProcessorComment,
       a.Name,
       a.Name
from
select
(
select sum(DATEDIFF(DAY,LeaveBreakup.StartDate,LeaveBreakup.EndDate)+1) AS totalNoOfDays,
       LeaveApplication.Id,
       LeaveBreakup.StartDate,
       LeaveBreakup.EndDate,
       LeaveApplication.ReasonForLeave,
       LeaveApplication.ProcessorComment,
       Team.Name,
       LeaveTypeDetail.Name
FROM LeaveApplication
INNER JOIN Employee ON LeaveApplication.Employee=Employee.Id
INNER JOIN Team ON Employee.Team=Team.Id
INNER JOIN LeaveBreakup ON LeaveApplication.Id=LeaveBreakup.LeaveApplication
INNER JOIN LeaveTypeDetail ON LeaveBreakup.LeaveType=LeaveTypeDetail.LeaveType
WHERE Employee.Team=5
  AND LeaveStatus!=0
  AND LeaveBreakup.StartDate BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '01-31-2016'
  AND LeaveBreakup.WhichHalf=0
GROUP BY LeaveApplication.Id,
         LeaveBreakup.StartDate,
         LeaveBreakup.EndDate,
         LeaveApplication.ReasonForLeave,
         LeaveApplication.ProcessorComment,
         Team.Name,
         LeaveTypeDetail.Name
)a
group by
a.Id,
a.StartDate,
a.EndDate,
a.ReasonForLeave,
a.ProcessorComment,
a.Name,
a.Name
ORDER BY a.StartDate
```